# How to modify array with recursion

Tags: php, recursion

I have array

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'free'];
$value = 10;
```

Need use recursion function.

So I wanna get array like this

```
$result = ['one' => ['two' => ['free' => 10]]];
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array in reverse and build the array from the furthest nested value and back.

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'free'];
$value = 10;

$arr = array_reverse($arr);

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if($key==0){
        $new[$val]= $value;
    }else{
        $new = [$val => $new]; //this overwrites the array with a new array with another layer
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/VRJOY

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's how to accomplish this with a recursive function:

```
$array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
$val = 10;

function do_array_thing($array, $val)
{
    if (count($array) > 0) {
        $key = array_pop($array);
        return do_array_thing($array, [$key => $val]);
    } else {
        return $val;
    }
}

print_r(do_array_thing($array, $val));
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [three] => Array
                        (
                            [four] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

)
```